# Microsoft Visual Studio Express not processing } correctly

Tags: c#

So, I am new to C#, and I was messing around creating a simple password form. This is the code to the password part

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStrings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PSW2;
            PSW2 = TextBox2.Text;
            if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;
            {
                if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
                    Process.Start("http://www.fanime.xyz/");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            else;
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
            }
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox2_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this it tells me that `}` is expected above the else for my if logic gate. Now, if you hadn't already noticed, the symbol above the else *is* a left facing bracket `}`. Is there a problem with my code or my computer, any answer would be ***GREAT***, Thanks!

Comment: That's not C++...

Comment: You've got tons of wrongly-placed `;`. They're not things you splatter about randomly at the end of lines.

Comment: the compiler put errors when i didn't, sorry.

Comment: I very much doubt that the compiler complained about a missing semicolon after `if (PSW2 == "MyPassword")` ...

Comment: no, but it did everywhere else so i just put them there. (probably not the best assumption to make).

Comment: @JasonTowan Could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Cause:**

Your if/else statement syntax is incorrect. You need to remove the `;` after `if` and `else`

**Solution:**

Change this:

```
if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;
{
    if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
        Process.Start("http://www.fanime.xyz/");
        Environment.Exit(0);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
else;
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
}
```

To this:

```
if (PSW2 == "MyPassword")
{
    if (PSW2 == "MyPassword")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
        Process.Start("http://www.fanime.xyz/");
        Environment.Exit(0);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
}
```

Comment: And after `if()`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't see how i have spent weeks trying to figure it out and that was it!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Comment: @JasonTowan Next time use [snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) so for example type if, tap TAB twice.

Answer (score 0):

All the semicolons after the `if` and `else` need to be removed:

```
    if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;

        if (PSW2 == "MyPassword") ;

    else;
```